# Keyboard ArrowDown in listbox using Selenium with C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-c#

I'm working in selenium c# automation, I'm trying to traverse down in list box values. `<ul>` and  `<li>`. I have tried many options in trial and error. The kind of code I'm trying to use is below. please find my piece of code.

I don't know why this does not work.

```
var resultset = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='Narrative_listbox']"));
var options = resultset.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));

foreach (var option in options)
{
   option.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown);
}
```

Comment: Try to send arrowdown key to the `resultset`, not to its `option`s

Comment: What happens when you try to run your code?

Comment: @wec I can't get you, what you are trying to say kindly elaborate it

Comment: @KatePaulk Getting error : element not interactable

Comment: @Thiyagarajan I mean what if instead `option.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown);` you would use `resultset.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown);`?

Comment: @wec getting error: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 'element not interactable

Comment: What would be the steps the user to take in manual mode? Like "click on a certain item, then press arrow down?" probably you miss some step like select the item before sending the keystroke? Make sure you emulate exactly the same flow the user is expected to pass.

Comment: @wec In Manual test case: when i click a button textarea will open list of values, when i press the arrow down keys,  i need to travel through the values. if any other options also please let me know.

Comment: So when you click a button and a list of values is shown is there any value selected by default or you just start pressing "down" and when you first press "down" the first available option is selected?

Comment: Another thing: can you test that you even enter `foreach` loop? Add some output to the loop body to make sure you even go into it. Even better output option items text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make sure the right element has the focus you could use Actions to send keyboard commands to the browser.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).Build().Perform();
```

In your situation this could look like:

```
var resultset = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='Narrative_listbox']"));
resultset.Click(); // Give it focus
var options = resultset.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));

foreach (var option in options)
{
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).Build().Perform();
}
```

Comment: Yes,It has selected the first item not travelling through rest of items.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying, but I added an example for your situation.

Comment: van Rejimersdal sorry for late reply its working

Comment: @Rejimersdak is it possible to get the count from resultset or get the text or iteration  count

Comment: @Thiyagarajan Yes, FindElements returns an ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> which has a Method Count. See the documentation: https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_ISearchContext_FindElements.htm

Comment: @Thiyagarajan Better to ask new questions with a new question, not as a comment.

Comment: @Neils van Reijmersdal Thanks for the guidance